# Looking for advices to make non-linear, multi-input programs (C)

Tags: c

I'm not completely sure if I'm asking it the right way, but as a non-English speaker, it's easy to get lost in the world of programming. I'm looking for a way to make programs as described in the title.

To illustrate: I want to make a Who Wants to Be a Millionaire program that prompts the user a question, and 4 answers.

For example:

Who stars in Star Wars? 
a, Mark Hamill b, Ray Liotta
c, Morgan Freeman d, James Dean

If the user enters the correct answer ('a), the program moves on to the next question. My question is, how to make this program more readable and efficient than simply putting a thousand of if-else branch? For example:

```
c=getchar();
if(c == 'a') printf("You got the right answer! Next question: ");
else printf("Sorry, wrong answer! Your game will end!");
```

My question is, what is the best way to get to the next question the same way, as if I have asked the first question? Sorry for the layman terms, but I don't really have an idea where to look.

Comment: Why did you choose C for this task? You'll be better off with C++ and it's standard libraries for working with strings and containers.

Comment: I have to do an assignment in C. This is one of them.

Comment: Is the question data stored in a file or do you hard-code it?

Comment: ^^^ use a language with containers straight off, though, TBH, containers that will stream to disk would be ideal, and you may need boost for that.

Comment: We haven't learned about files yet. I type them.

Comment: Obviously, you don't code each question explicitly. Write a game framework that will deal with input, scoring and advancing in the game, then have a database of questions, which could just be a text file.

Comment: Yeah. how about a csv format?  'Who stars in Star Wars,Mark Hamill,Ray Liotta,Morgan Freeman,James Dean'.  The correct answer is always first and the question poser function randomly displays the other choices.  On line of text per question - easy to stream in/out and to edit with any text editor.

Comment: @iksemyonov I disagree with you. C is perfectly well-suited for the task. Please don't discourage beginners.

Comment: @FUZxxl when else would you discourage beginners?  Why wait until they find out that C has no containers, no classes, no serialization libraries and no string type worthy of the name?

Comment: @MartinJames You shouldn't. You can do all these things in C just fine. But if you tell people that it can't be done, they might never try. And yes, there are containers (glib), classes (make your own) and serialization libraries (protobuf, libxml, libjson, sqlite, etc etc). You just have to use them.

Comment: Is it alright to answer this question? I've been in a situation today where I was prohibited to answer a simple question, so now I'm not sure it this one is ok to answer.

Comment: @MartinJames why do we need containers that stream to disk? Do you mean that they would simplify reading the data structures to / from files as opposed to implementing `operator<</>>()` by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track regarding elimination of code. When there is a repetitive task like that, it's right time to step back and think a little. Many beginners solve repetitive problems by hardcoding a long long `switch` or `if` statement. Now, given you have neither (a) files nor (b) containers at your disposal, I'd suggest a layout as follows.

Define a structure for every question like so (forgive my rusty C, hopefully I get it right):

```
typedef struct _Question {
    char *question;
    char *answers[4];
    char correctAnswer;
} Question;
```

Then, make an array of those, either dynamic (`Question* questions = (Question*)malloc(n*sizeof(Question))`) or static (`Question questions[n]`, but then you need to know how many questions you have beforehand) (since you have a hardcoded amount of questions, it can be static, but in the long run, it better be a dynamic array). Make a function to populate the array with actual data before the game. Then, turn the part you mentioned, that asks for the input and compares the input to the right answer, into a loop, for example like so:

```
int current = 0; char c; int fail = 0;
do {
    /*print the question contained in questions[current].question*/
    c = getchar();
    if (c == 'q')
        break;
    if (c == questions[current].correctAnswer) {
        /*print a "good" statement*/
        ++current;
    } else {
        /*print a "fail" statement */
        fail = 1;
    }
} while (current < num_of_questions && fail != 1);
```

Of course, this is a very crude way of doing it. Ideally, you want to read the question data in from a file to make the code more flexible (hardcoding data is a bad idea in general, though there are exceptions to this rule. this kind of data, though, surely belong in a file). I haven't touched scoring, levels, etc. that can be put in the game as well.

Edit: Worth noting maybe that this game is linear, for you can only go from question `i` to question `i+1` or fail and leave the game.